# Laravel DB::select syntax error or access violation error (works as native query)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Using the Laravel DB facade trying to execute the following query:

```
    $sql = "
        SELECT P.*, PTR.score
        FROM reviews R, products_to_reviews PTR, j_products P
        WHERE R.id = ? AND PTR.review_id = R.id AND P.id = PTR.product_id
        ORDER BY ? ?
        LIMIT ?
    ";

    $data = \DB::select($sql,[$reviewID,$orderBy,$orderByDirection,$take]);
```

I get the following error message:

> lluminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?
> LIMIT 3' at line 4 (SQL:
> SELECT P.*, PTR.score
> FROM reviews R, products_to_reviews PTR, j_products P
> WHERE R.id = 1 AND PTR.review_id = R.id AND P.id = PTR.product_id
> ORDER BY PTR.score desc
> LIMIT 3
> )

However, the sql code in the error works as a native query when executed directly towards the database.

Edit:
I have narrowed it down to the order by direction part. If I change:

```
ORDER BY ? ?
```

to

```
ORDER BY ? DESC
```

The sql statement executes without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `DB::raw()`?

try `$data = \DB::select($sql,[$reviewID,$orderBy,$orderByDirection,$take]);`

Comment: I did not use DB::raw() initially, but added it hoping it would solve the problem. Even without it I get the same error message.

Comment: @ErikT This is a syntax error, order by two columns need split by `,`, like below:
`ORDER BY ?, ? LIMIT ?`

Comment: The second question mark (?) in:

ORDER BY ? ? 

Is used to determine direction and should therefore not have a comma before it. For reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html